# Proof that addition on a Banach space is continuous

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

What I have so far:

Let $(W,+,\cdot,\Vert\cdot\Vert)$ be a Banach space. We have the map

$$+ : W\times W \to W.$$

The topology $T$ on $W$ is given by

$$T = \{U\subseteq W ~\big|~ \forall u\in U : \exists~ r>0 : B_u(r)\subseteq U\},$$

where

$$B_x(r) = \{w\in W ~\big|~ \Vert x-w \Vert < r\}$$
and $T^\times$ is the product topology on $W\times W$.

We must show that for any $U\in T$,

$$\text{preim}_+(U) \in T^\times.$$

I've got that

$$ \text{preim}_+(U) = \{(u,v)\in W\times W ~\big|~ \exists~r>0 : B_{u+v}(r)\subseteq U\}, $$

but I'm not sure how to continue. I tried to construct an open product subset of $W\times W$ which is contained in $\text{preim}_+(B_x(r))$ for arbitrary $x\in U$, but couldn't make any progress.

Thanks.

Comment: you have to prove show $pre(U)$ is an open of $W \times W$ when $U$ is an open ball, which is indeed obvious. but you are really complicating things I wonder why.

Comment: @user1952009 It may seem obvious to you, but it isn't obvious to me. If you have a simpler way of proving this, then I'd love to hear it!

Comment: $+$ maps the $\epsilon$-balls of $W \times W$ to $2\epsilon$-balls of $W$

Comment: @user1952009 This makes sense to me intuitively in the finite dimensional case, but I'm not clear on how exactly we should define the  norm on $W\times W$ in general. I apologise if my ignorance is frustrating.

Comment: and that $\{ u \in W \ \mid \ \|u+v - x\| < r\ \}$ is open in $W$ is obvious, hence $\{ u,v \in W \times W \ \mid \ \|u+v - x\| < r\ \}$ is open in $W \times W$ is obvious too ?

Comment: when I said $\epsilon$-balls of $W \times W$ I didn't mean a norm on $W \times W$  , I meant the set of couples $(u,v)$ where $u$ is in some $\epsilon$-ball of $W$ and $v$ in another.  and a norm can be $\|(u,v)\| = \|u\|+\|v\|$. and since $+$ is commutative, proving that $u \to u+v$ is continuous is enough

Comment: do you know that only the bounded linear operators are continuous among the linear operators on Banach spaces ? you should probably prove that, it is in every course/book

Comment: @user1952009 I can prove that assuming that the space of bounded linear operators is a Banach space with the operator norm, but for that I need to distribute a limit over addition. Hence the question :P

Comment: $u \to u+v$ clearly maps $B_\epsilon(a)$ to $B_\epsilon(a+v)$ (which implies the continuity of $+$) and that's all you need for proving the continuity of bounded operators $X \to Y$

Comment: @user1952009 Thanks, that's what I needed. I'm disappointed I didn't see that haha

Comment: @user213045 Feel free to write your own answer to this question and accept it :)